# Type mismatch after running

Tags: java, type-mismatch, mismatch

```java
package skater;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestSkater 
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:/pairs.txt"));
        String name1 = null, name2 = null, Country = null;
        double [] Technical = new double [8];
        double [] Performance = new double[8];

        try {  
            while(sc.hasNext())
            {
                name1=sc.nextLine();
                name2 = sc.nextLine();
                Country = sc.nextLine();

                for (int t = 0; t<Technical.length; t++)
                {
                    Technical[t] = sc.nextDouble();
                }
                for(int y = 0; y<Performance.length; y++)
                {
                    Performance[y] = sc.nextDouble();
                }
                // Skater [] skaters = new Skater[20];
                Skater S1 = new Skater(name1,name2,Country,Technical,Performance);
                System.out.println(S1);
                sc.nextLine();
            }   
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.print("Bad program");
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I run my code without the try and catch I get an `InputMismatchException`. It's reading from a file that has all the names of the teams with their scores and countries. It's formatted like this:

```
smith

jones

australia

4.2 5.1 3.8 2.9 5.0 4.6 4.9 4.3

4.9 4.8 5.8 3.8 4.9 4.6 5.0 4.5

lennon

murray

england

2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8

3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4 3.5 3.6 3.7 3.8
```

I know that the `nextLine()` is telling it to look at the next line of data, And the `nextDouble()` that I am using for the arrays `Performance` and `Technical`, is telling it to look at the next double in line.

I can't figure out why it is giving me this error. I think it's because when it moves onto the first name of the next team it is still seeing it as a double from the array `Performance`, but I can't figure out how to fix that problem.

Comment: I see you print out the Skater object after it is created.  Does it correctly output the first object and fail on the second (indicating, as you suggest, that the issue is reading the name after the previous entries performance values) or does it fail on the first item (indicating a problem parsing the input in general)?

Comment: it fails right after it done reading all the objects of the first pair. As soon as it goes to read the first object of the next team which is the first name, it crashes

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without knowing what the Scanner functions (nextLine, nextDouble) are really doing and the exact format of the file you area reading.

Assuming that:
**nextLine** reads text to the end of line
**nextDouble** reads and parses text to the next break/space
Then, by the way you are reading the input, I assume it's in the format:

```
Name1
Name2
Country
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0
```

If the assumptions are correct and that's not the format of the input then there's your problem.

If you are sure that the nextLine text entries are being read fine then an option may be to read the line as a string, split on space (or comma, or semicolon or whatever seperates them) and parse them yourself e.g.

```
string[] tmp = sc.nextLine().split(' ');
for(int t = 0; t<Technical.length; t++)
    Technical[t] = Double.parseDouble(tmp[t]);
```